# detect open browser and parse html

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

Is there a way to create a winforms app, that detects an open browser and then reads the html.

i need to create an app that checks your browser and if there are fields like address, email etc. the winforms app must automatically fill it in.

Comment: Such a program, even if doable, has privacy ramifications that cannot be tolerated.

Comment: this is for facial recognition, and auto submitting username and passwords in your browser, if you are in front of your PC. nothing malicious bout that ?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this kind of work you need to inject your code into the browser process. You can implement your application as an add-on of the browser.